# P(A-B) vs. P(A)-P(B)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Could you help me understand where is the mistake in the reasoning below? I've checked other posts but I couldn't find an answer to this specific issue. Thank you in advance.

Let $A$, $B$ and $X$ be sets, then
$$\begin{align*}
&X\in \mathcal{P} (A-B)\Leftrightarrow\\
&\Leftrightarrow X\subseteq (A-B)\\
&\Leftrightarrow \forall y\in X,y\in(A-B)\\
&\Leftrightarrow\forall y\in X, (y\in A \wedge y\notin B)\\
&\Leftrightarrow(\forall y\in X, y\in A) \wedge (\forall y\in X, y\notin B) \\
&\Rightarrow(\forall y\in X, y\in A) \wedge (\exists  y\in X, y\notin B)\\
&\Leftrightarrow(\forall y\in X, y\in A) \wedge \neg(\forall  y\in X, y\in B)\\
&\Leftrightarrow (X\subseteq A) \wedge \neg (X\subseteq B)\\
&\Leftrightarrow (X\subseteq A) \wedge (X\nsubseteq  B)\\
&\Leftrightarrow (X\in \mathcal{P} (A)) \wedge (X\notin \mathcal{P}(B))\\
&\Leftrightarrow X\in (\mathcal{P} (A) - \mathcal{P}(B))\\
\end{align*}$$

Therefore,

$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal{P} (A-B)\subseteq\mathcal{P} (A) - \mathcal{P}(B)
\end{align*}$$

On the other hand,

$$\begin{align*}
\varnothing \in \mathcal{P} (A-B)\\
\varnothing \notin \mathcal{P} (A) - \mathcal{P}(B)
\end{align*}$$
So
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal{P} (A-B)\nsubseteq\mathcal{P} (A) - \mathcal{P}(B)
\end{align*}$$

But this is a contradiction.

Comment: Well, just go through your set of implications line by line with $X=\emptyset$.  You'll see that at some point you pass from statements about $\forall y\in X$ (which are harmless, since vacuously true claims are still true) to asserting $\exists y\in X$ without justification.

Comment: I agree with lulu, and specifically you make that error in passing from line 5 to line 6. If X happens to be empty, the second conjunct in line 5 holds but that in line 6 does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a contradiction (for the final result), the empty set is always a subset of any set, so it always belongs to the power set of any set, but $\mathcal{P}(A) \setminus \mathcal{P}(B)$ is not a power set of some set $C$, so you clearly don't have any relations between both sets, they don't even live in the same "world".

Draw a Venn Diagram and you will see that any subset of $A$ that has at least one element in $A \setminus B$ belongs to $\mathcal{P}(A) \setminus \mathcal{P}(B)$. But it can have elements of $B$.

On the other hand, subsets of $\mathcal{P}(A\setminus B)$ are those which all elements are in $A \setminus B$.

So each non empty set in $\mathcal{P}(A \setminus B)$ is in $\mathcal{P}(A) \setminus \mathcal{P}(B)$ but this is not the case for the empty set.

In summary there is a mistake on your $5^{th}$ to $6^{th}$ line: there may not exist an element in your set $X$