# Proof involving P(A-B) and P(a)-P(B)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Could somebody help me prove or disprove the statement below. Thank you in advance.

If $A$ and $B$ are sets, $A\cap B = \varnothing$  and $\mathcal{P} (A)$ is the power set of $A$ (the set of all subsests of $A$) , then $\mathcal{P} (A)-\mathcal{P} (B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A-B)$

This is my attempt. The statement is true, see proof below.

$\mathcal{P} (A)-\mathcal{P} (B) = \mathcal{P} (A) - \varnothing \subseteq \mathcal{P} (A) = \mathcal{P}(A-B)$

Comment: Can you clarify what is $P(B)$, and why $P(B) = \emptyset$?

Comment: Are you speaking about probabilities?

Comment: OP has an [unsuccessful attempt for a variant of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4721139/pa-b-vs-pa-pb). In that, $P(B)$ was the power set.

Comment: You'd need to provide some words to explain what you're doing, or at least what your reasoning is. EG In a naive read of your equations, one might assume you are claiming that $P(B) = \emptyset$, when actually what you (might be) thinking is that $P(A)\cap P(B) = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A\cap B=\emptyset$, it follows that $A\setminus B=A$. So the inclusion is obvious. In fact,
[$\mathcal{P}(A)\setminus\mathcal{P}(B)]\sqcup\{\emptyset\}=\mathcal{P}(A\setminus B)$.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't think it is correct to say that we have an equality, as the empty set is in pow(A-B) but it is not in pow(A) - pow(B)

Comment: Yes, you are right. But that is the only "extra element", i.e., $(\mathcal{P}(A)\setminus \mathcal{P}(B))\cup \{\emptyset\}=\mathcal{P}(A\setminus B)$.

Comment: @Fuzzy Do you accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Let pow(A)->power set of A

pow(B)->power set of B

Since A and B are disjoint follows

pow(A) and pow(B) are disjoint

Thus pow(A)-pow(B)=pow(A)----1

Also pow(A-B) = pow(A) -----2(trivial)

From 1 and 2
Indeed, pow(A)-pow(B)=pow(A-B)

Take an ex

A={1,2,3}, B={4,5}

Pow(A)= {null,{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{2,3},{1,3},{1,2,3}}

Pow(B)={null,{4},{5},{4,5}}

Pow(A)-pow(B)=pow(A)

Pow(A-B)=pow({1,2,3}-{4,5})=pow({1,2,3}) = pow(A)

Thus we can see that Pow(A)-pow(B)=pow(A-B)

Comment: Thank you. But I don't think that "pow(A)-pow(B)=pow(A)" that you wrote is correct, as the empty set is in pow(A) but it is not in pow(A)-pow(B)